# Finding only records where a value occurred with a later timestamp than another value

Tags: sql, db2

Hopefully I can phrase this question right --

I have a table that has ID numbers for users and a field that contains 'events' such as 'logged in', 'did X', 'did Y', etc.  So a single user ID may have tons of records in this table.  There's also an associated timestamp field for each of these records.

I'm trying to put together a query for this table where I can find ONLY the user IDs where 'Did X', occurred with a more recent timestamp than 'Did Y'.

There's a chance that a user can 'Did X' or 'Did Y' multiple times, but I need only the user IDs who have 'Did X' more recently than 'Did Y'.  There is also the chance that a user may never have 'Did Y', but the ones I'm looking for will at least always include 'Did X'.

I've been trying various joins and self joins and whatnot, but I'm striking out so far.  Feels like there's a simple solution I'm just overlooking.

I appreciate any and all help here.

Edit: This link provided in the comment below solved this for me more or less.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=263f8394751590ab0d440c53b09e573a

Comment: Please, provide some sample data and the result desired on this data. For example, you may edit the query at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=263f8394751590ab0d440c53b09e573a) link in some similar way (WITH part) and post your new link. Or just edit your question with the same data example.

Comment: This link pretty much solved it for me.  
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting this right...you could get users who did action x and not exist an action y from the same user after doing x

```
select * from tabla t1
where t1.action = "did X" 
and not exists (select * from tabla t2 where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.action = "did y" and t2.fecha > t1.Fecha)
```

hope thats what you mean.